# Spring -MVC use session attribute in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, controller

I have a method where I require the argument name and I have it set as a session attribute as it will be fixed through out the session. However, I have trouble adding it to the function. Any help is appreciated.

LoginController class that sets the session attribute

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"name", "date"})
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
LoginService service;


/*
 *  Map /login to this method 
 *  localhost:8080/spring-mvc/login
 *  spring-mvc -> dispatcher (todo-servlet.xml)
 *  dispatcher detects login url
 *  dispatcher use view resolver to find .jsp file based on String. In this case, login
 *  view resolver locates login.jsp and shows the content to user via http
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
// Mark this method as an actual repsonse back to user
@ResponseBody
public String test() {
    return "Hello, world!";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/")
public String returnLogin() {
    return "redirect:/loginPage";
}

// Only handles get request from the login page
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() { 
    // search through the view resolver for login.jsp
    return "login";
}

// Only handles post request from the login page
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
// @RequestParm to be used for user input
// Model is used to supply attributes to views
// ModelMap has the same functionality has model except it has an addition function where it allows a collection of attributes
public String handleLogin(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password, ModelMap model) {
    if (service.validateUser(name, password)) {
    // Send name to .jsp 
    // use addAttrible( nameAtJSP, nameInRequestParam ) to check for null
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    model.addAttribute("passWelcome", password);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    model.addAttribute("date", date);
    }
    
    else {
        model.put("errorMessage","Invalid credentials");
        return loginPage();
    }
    return "welcome";   
}
```

My controller class. I've commented the part that I need to add the session attribute.

```java
@Controller
public class ToDoController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ToDoService service;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showToDo(ModelMap model, String name, String date) {
        model.addAttribute("toDos", service.retrieveTodos("in28Minutes"));
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("date", date);
        // Only returns to the jsp
        return "list-todos";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addToDo() {
        return "addToDo";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addToDo(ModelMap model,@RequestParam String description) {
        // SESSION ATTRIBUTE NAME
        model.addAttribute("name");
        service.addTodo((String) model.get("name"), description, new Date(), false);
        model.clear();
        return "redirect:/list-todo";
    }
```

Comment: Set to a `HttpSession`?

Comment: @pirho can you elaborate with code/

Comment: You: " I have it set as a session attribute", how did you set it?

Comment: @pirho added the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@SessionAttributes` doesn't do what you are trying to achieve.

From javadoc of [`@SessionAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html):

> **NOTE:** Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond
> to a specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently stored
> in a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once the
> handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore,
> use this facility for such conversational attributes which are
> supposed to be stored in the session temporarily during the course of
> a specific handler's conversation.
>
> For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object,
> use the traditional `session.setAttribute` method instead.

So, what you need to do is:

```java
public String handleLogin(@RequestParam String name, 
                          @RequestParam String password,
                          ModelMap model,
                          HttpSession httpSession) {

    // your code here
    
    httpSession.setAttribute("name", name);

    // your code here
}
```

And then you can retrieve this session attribute in your `ToDoController` as `httpSession.getAttribute("name");`